# Echo from database in collation "latin1_swedish_ci" results in questionmark symbols on webpage

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters, collation, meta

I feel like this should be a simple fix, but the answer eludes me. Ive tried googling, and searching here... to no avail.

i have a long text stored in my database.
The collation is latin1_swedish_ci"
and when I see it in the database, it is stored correctly. For example:

```
     string= Sally was walking one day and saw Tom.  Tom said "Hi, Sally!" Sally's response was "Hi, Tom."
```

every " or ' shows up as a white question mark on a black diamond.

I want to

```
     $result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT string FROM Table WHERE 1")
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          echo $row['string']; 
     }
```

and have all of the characters show up.
can anyone help?

Comment: are you sure they are real quotes and not 'smart-quotes' (curly quotes)?

Comment: have your tried echo htmlentities($row['string']);

Comment: @dagon I don't know... I know that i typed them into my database, i don't know how to tell the difference.

Comment: @ jeff I have not, i will try that now

Comment: @jeff that got rid of the question marks.. unfortunately it got rid of everything else in the string with them.

Comment: `htmlentities` is a hack.  Go with utf8 all the way through.

Comment: @Rick James should i try to convert the current collation to utf8? Is it possible/worth it?  I am open to all solutions, This is an overwhelming project I am tackling for myself, and maybe others, its early enough that if the conversion is generally successful and trustworthy I can give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I found a post that didn't come up before.
This solution to a similar problem was offered by Emil H:

> MySQL performs character set conversions on the fly to something
>   called the connection charset. You can specify this charset using the
>   sql statement
>
> SET NAMES utf8 or use a specific API function such as
>   mysql_set_charset():
>
> mysql_set_charset("utf8", $conn); If this is done correctly there's no
>   need to use functions such as utf8_encode() and utf8_decode().
>
> You also have to make sure that the browser uses the same encoding.
>   This is usually done using a simple header:
>
> header('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8'); (Note that the
>   charset is called utf-8 in the browser but utf8 in MySQL.)
>
> In most cases the connection charset and web charset are the only
>   things that you need to keep track of, so if it still doesn't work
>   there's probably something else your doing wrong. Try experimenting
>   with it a bit, it usually takes a while to fully understand.
>
> shareedit edited Mar 25 '09 at 12:17 answered Mar 25 '09 at 11:52
>
> Emil H 28k75778

after reading that, I looked up the php code she/he was talking about and found that there is an sqli equivilant, with different syntax.

(PHP 5 >= 5.0.5, PHP 7)
mysqli::set_charset -- mysqli_set_charset — Sets the default client character set

Description ¶

Object oriented style

bool mysqli::set_charset ( string $charset )
Procedural style

bool mysqli_set_charset ( mysqli $link , string $charset )
Sets the default character set to be used when sending data from and to the database server.

I hope this helps anyone having the problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to fix yours with this example.

SQL:

```
    CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `string` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('1', 'Sally was walking one day and saw Tom.  Tom said \"Hi, Sally!\" Sally\'s response was \"Hi, Tom.\"');
```

PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT id, string FROM test WHERE id = 1";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['string'];
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: that may work... and if the story of Tom and Sally were all i was dealing with that would be good enough.  Unfortunately, thats a TON of editing to every entry i already have in... (something like 300 entries (so far) several of them are 4 pages of typed text) I was hoping for a more elegant answer.  If there isn't a better answer i will have learned something for the future entries. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Have you tried:  html_entity_decode($row['string']);

Comment: Nothing happened, looks the same.

Comment: The diamond and question mark, I once had an issue with it while working with images, I used ob_start(); in the header  before encoding it with base64_encode();. you should try ob_start(); in the header.

Comment: what does ob_start(); do? I am interested in solving the problem, but i also want to understand why it fixes the problem, so that 1. i understand more an can therefore do more, 2. so that i can apply the logic to other problems in the future, and 3. so that i understand if there will be other repercussions to using that fix... after some quick reading... I cant understand why it would help... but I'll give it a try.

Comment: It did nothing... the ob_start() appears to just be a buffering technique to increase efficiency of page load and server processing capacity to send information in large chunks... I don't see why it would have helped after looking up some other questions on here

Answer (score 0):

A single question mark is one kind of symptom; a string of question marks is another; and black diamond with a question mark is yet another problem.  Sweep the slate clean...  Get rid of all encoding functions and...

- Have the data in the client be utf8-encoded, and
- Establish that the connection is `CHARACTER SET utf8`, and
- Have the tables/columns be `CHARACTER SET utf8`, and
- On html pages, use `<meta charset=UTF-8>`.

Comment: I will look up how to convert my sql to utf-8... i saw a question about that yesterday.